# Optimization of a Virtuemart Attribute Query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a select query below, what it does is it selects all the products matching a certain attribute from a Virtuemart table. The attribute table is rather large (almost 6000 rows). Is there any way to optimize the query below or are there any other process that might be helpful, I already tried adding indexes to one and even two tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `jos_vm_product`.`product_id`,
    `jos_vm_product_attribute`.`attribute_name`, 
    `jos_vm_product_attribute`.`attribute_value`,
    `jos_vm_product_attribute`.`product_id` 
FROM (`jos_vm_product`) 
    RIGHT JOIN `jos_vm_product_attribute` 
        ON `jos_vm_product`.`product_id` = `jos_vm_product_attribute`.`product_id`  
WHERE ((`jos_vm_product_attribute`.`attribute_name` = 'Size') 
    AND ((`jos_vm_product_attribute`.`attribute_value` = '6.5')  
        OR (`jos_vm_product_attribute`.`attribute_value` = '10')))    
GROUP BY `jos_vm_product`.`product_sku`   
ORDER BY CONVERT(`jos_vm_product_attribute`.`attribute_value`, SIGNED INTEGER)
LIMIT 0, 24
```

Here is the results of the EXPLAIN table:

```
id  select_type     table                       type    possible_keys                                               key             key_len     ref     rows    Extras
1   SIMPLE          jos_vm_product_attribute    range   idx_product_attribute_name,attribute_value,attribute_name   attribute_value 765         NULL    333     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          jos_vm_product              eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                     PRIMARY         4           shoemark_com_shop.jos_vm_product_attribute.product_id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the `jos_vm_product_attribute.attribute_name` index with a composite index on `jos_vm_product_attribute.attribute_name` and `jos_vm_product_attribute.attribute_value` (in that order) should help this query.  Currently, it's only using an index in the `WHERE` condition for `jos_vm_product_attribute.attribute_value`, but this new index will be usable for both parts of the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Hi G-Nugget, thanks for your reply. I tried doing what you suggested but the following error occurred:
#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Comment: Edit: Actually, I shortened the character lengths of both these columns then re-ran the SQL alter table SQL command to add in the composite index, it worked, no error occurred. I'll check if there is a difference in speed. Thanks!

Comment: @TarunDhanwani What are the data types and character sets for the columns?  If possible, you should try to fully index the columns.  If you're using a utf-8 collation, that effectively triples the length of the field in the index which will cause it to reach the 1000 byte limit quicker.

Comment: Hi G-Nugget, it did improve the speed a little bit, but it still takes some time for the query to execute. I have 4 columns: attribute_id(int 11), product_id(int 11), attribute_name(char50) and attribute_value(char255). All of the columns are indexed and att_name and att_value have utf-8 collation. Should I use a different collation for these two columns? Thanks again.

Comment: @TarunDhanwani Please post a new `EXPLAIN`.  `attribute_name` should be a `VARCHAR` unless every value is 50 characters long.  If you know that you aren't going to use any characters outside the `latin1` character set, which you probably won't for the attribute names, that would be a better choice.  `attribute_value` _should_ be `utf8` since it is user data and you don't want to miss anything they put in.